# Angular 9 with RxJs - combining 2 observables results in data but async pipe always sees a null result

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I have 2 observables that return data from Firebase, and no matter what type of combination operator I use (forkJoin, CombineLatest etc) the async pipe does not receive the data.

I have an AuthService, with a method that initialises the user from a Firebase realtime database:

```
  private initUser(firebaseUser: firebase.User) {
    const myUser: User = {account: {}, profile: {}};
    const userId = `US_${firebaseUser.uid}`;

    const accountSnapshot: Observable<UserAccount> = this.db
      .object(`/users/accounts/${userId}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(first()) as Observable<UserAccount>;

    const profileSnapshot: Observable<UserProfile> = this.db
      .object(`/users/profiles/${userId}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(first()) as Observable<UserProfile>;

    forkJoin([accountSnapshot, profileSnapshot])
      .subscribe((result: [UserAccount, UserProfile]) => {
        if (result) {
          myUser.account = result[0];
          myUser.profile = result[1];
          this.setCurrentUser(myUser);
        }
      });
  }
```

CurrentUser is set up as a subject with getter/setter:

```
  private currentUser = new Subject<User>();

  public get getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.currentUser.asObservable();
  }

  public setCurrentUser(user: User): void {
    this.currentUser.next(user);
  }
```

In the consuming component:

```
  currentUser$: Observable<User>;
  user: User;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser;
    this.currentUser$.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
```

and in the template:

```
<p>Email: {{ ((currentUser$ | async)?.account).email }}</p>. <- ** DOES NOT WORK **
<p>Email: {{ (user?.account).email }}</p> <- ** DOES WORK **
```

Now, here is the strange part. If I change the `initUser` method to NOT combine the observables from firebase, but to get them separately (and set the users profile and account as separate operations), then `async` works. Like this:

```
accountSnapshot.subscribe((account: UserAccount) => {
  if (account) {
    myUser.account = account;
    this.setCurrentUser(myUser);
  }
});
profileSnapshot.subscribe((profile: UserProfile) => {
  if (profile) {
    myUser.profile = profile;
    this.setCurrentUser(myUser);
  }
});
```

then the async pipe works.

I have tried changing the `forkJoin` to `CombineLatest` and `zip`. I've also tried removing the `pipe(first())` but the `async` pipe *never* works.

Why is this?

Is there something wrong with async or with my code, or maybe my understanding of how async works...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `Subject` fires before your view is ready. You should change it to a `ReplaySubject` so the latest value(s) get replayed on subscription.

```
private currentUser = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
```

---

(out of scope of question)

Besides that, it seems a bit odd to use a nested `subscribe` like you have in your `initUser`. To me you can simplify your code to the following:

```
private readonly initUser$ = new Subject<firebase.User>();

readonly currentUser$: Observable<User> = this.initUser$.pipe(
  map((user) => `US_${user.uid}`),
  switchMap((userId) => combineLatest([
    this.db.object<UserAccount>(`/users/accounts/${userId}`).valueChanges(),
    this.db.object<UserProfile>(`/users/profiles/${userId}`).valueChanges()
  ])),
  map(([ account, profile ]) => ({ account, profile } as User)),
  shareReplay(1)
);

private initUser(firebaseUser: firebase.User) {
  this.initUser$.next(firebaseUser);
}
```

In your consuming component you can then just use the service `currentUser$` observable to get the user details

Comment: @rmcsharry I've updated my answer with a bit of rewritten code

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you have already susbcribed to that forkjoin :-

Change it to :-

```
this.currentUser$ = forkJoin([accountSnapshot, profileSnapshot])
      .pipe(map((result: [UserAccount, UserProfile]) => {
        if (result) {
          myUser.account = result[0];
          myUser.profile = result[1];
          this.setCurrentUser(myUser);
        }
      }));
```

then use this currentUser$ with asyncpipe in your template.